# Linking to a category list item

Tags: joomla-4.x, url, non-sef-url

I have a Joomla 4 menu item of type "List All Categories in an Article Category Tree". The menu item is FAQ, which sits under another menu item labelled Help. There is a category with an alias getting-started, and in that category, an article with alias checklist. So, with SEO turned on, navigating through that structure to the article results in url help/faq/getting-started/checklist.html . That's all fine.

Now I would like to link to that article from somewhere else on the web site. Of course I could just link to help/faq/getting-started/checklist.html, but it seems like a better idea to link to the article id, in case the structure changes or in case SEO is turned off (am I right that this is better?) So I created a link to index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=11, which almost works, but not quite; the url ends up looking like help/faq/different-category/checklist.html. different-category is a category that has an id that happens to be the same id as the article id, not sure if that's just a coincidence. Anyway, this url doesn't work.

So I turned off SEO to see what the url looks like for the article. It looks something like this:

```
/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=11:checklist&catid=12&Itemid=135
```

So, in addition to the article id (11), the url includes both the category id (12) and the id (135) of the menu item "List All Categories in an Article Category Tree". It also includes the article alias, though I can remove that from the url and it still works. So that works whether SEO is turned on or off, but it seems rather tightly coupled to the current category structure and menu structure. Is this the right (only?) way to link to such an article?

Oho, it seemed I can also remove catid, and that also works with SEO turned off:

```
/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=11&Itemid=135
```

However, with SEO turned on, it seems like catid really is needed:

```
/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=11&catid=12&Itemid=135
```

Is this as short as it gets?